# Keyboard phonegap

Tags: cordova, keyboard

I'm working with an application for mobile using phonegap (js + css + html). Is there  a way when i open a page the keyboard comes opened? I looked for it, but i couldnt fing anything.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Often, when an input receives focus, the keyboard is displayed. Perhaps you could set focus on a textbox after the page loads?

Comment: unfortunatelly, no! =( i tried some ways of making it, but nothing worked.. maybe im just missing the right one =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this [Phonegap Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard) on Github. The Documentation is not very verbose but it seems like you can open the Software keyboard from javascript. You could fire it in the deviceReady() Function.

Comment: thank you, @dan.. i had to make some modification, but this was the way ;)